# VS 2015 add watermark to JavaScript file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, watermark

I want to add watermark on my JavaScript file (created from a gulp task), to indicate that it is dynamically generated.

I have seen that if you have grunt or gulp file, you see a watermark on the bottom right corner. Also "web compiler extension" puts the word "Generated" on the compiled files.

Example:

[image]